# IT Hit cookies pass issue

Tags: javascript, java, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I have a problem with IT Hit and hope you will be able to help me.
The problem is that I can’t send custom cookies to WebDav Mini-Redirector. Everything is installed correctly and JS generates URL: `dav5:ItemUrl=http://localhost:8040/fs/158758.txt;MountUrl=http:// localhost:8040/fs/;Browser=Chrome;SearchIn=Current;CookieNames=JSESSIONID,BAYEUX_BROWSER;Command=Edit`

So I want send cookies JSESSIONID and BAYEUX_BROWSER, which are in Chrome (I’ve check it). Suddenly after running that url I’ve got error (content of log file below):

```
2017-12-14 11:46:34,339 - document_opener - DEBUG - Product info: {'LegalCopyright': u'Copyright \xae IT Hit, Ltd 2017.', 'InternalName': u'ITHit.DocumentOpener.dav5', 'FileVersion': u'4.0.2375.0', 'CompanyName': u'IT Hit, Ltd', 'PrivateBuild': None, 'LegalTrademarks': None, 'Comments': None, 'ProductName': u'IT Hit Edit Document Opener 4 v4.0.2375.0', 'SpecialBuild': None, 'ProductVersion': u'4.0.2375.0', 'FileDescription': u'IT Hit Edit Document Opener 4 v4.0.2375.0', 'OriginalFilename': u'ITHit.DocumentOpener.dav5.Exe'}
2017-12-14 11:46:34,387 - document_opener.gui - INFO - ================================================================================
2017-12-14 11:46:34,388 - document_opener.gui - INFO - System Info:
2017-12-14 11:46:34,388 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     System: Windows
2017-12-14 11:46:34,388 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Node: USERNAME
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Release: 10
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Version: 10.0.10586
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Machine: AMD64
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO - Browsers installed:
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Firefox v.57.0.2.6549 on C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     IE v.11.0.10586.1106 on C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     Chrome v.62.0.3202.94 on C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO -     EDGE v.11.0.10586.1176 on C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO - Config data: show_message_as_modal: True | extend_expired_cookies: None | expired_time_plus_hour: 24
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO - ================================================================================
2017-12-14 11:46:34,390 - document_opener.gui - INFO - Incoming URL: dav5:ItemUrl=http://localhost:8040/fs/158758.txt;MountUrl=http://localhost:8040/fs/;Browser=Chrome;SearchIn=Current;CookieNames=JSESSIONID,BAYEUX_BROWSER;Command=Edit
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO - splited URL: {'searchin': ['Current'], 'mounturl': 'http://localhost:8040/fs/', 'cookienames': ['JSESSIONID', 'BAYEUX_BROWSER'], 'itemurl': ['http://localhost:8040/fs/158758.txt'], 'command': 'Edit', 'browser': 'Chrome'}
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO - Parsed Parameters :
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    mountingpath: http://localhost:8040/fs/
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    searchin: [u'Current']
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    cookienames: [u'JSESSIONID', u'BAYEUX_BROWSER']
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    itempath: [u'http://localhost:8040/fs/158758.txt']
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    command: edit
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    loginurl: None
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    browser: Chrome
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    loginname: 
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.gui - INFO -    windriveletter: None
2017-12-14 11:46:34,391 - document_opener.cookies - INFO - Parse Chrome cookies
2017-12-14 11:46:34,398 - document_opener.cookies - DEBUG - Read cookies file C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies
2017-12-14 11:46:35,188 - document_opener.cookies - INFO - Total read cookies: 3818 and with Error: 0
2017-12-14 11:46:35,213 - document_opener.gui - DEBUG - List Cookies:
2017-12-14 11:46:35,214 - document_opener.gui - DEBUG - List Domain shift: [u'localhost']
2017-12-14 11:46:35,224 - document_opener.gui - DEBUG - cook is expired True
2017-12-14 11:46:35,273 - document_opener.gui - ERROR - Create mbox ended with error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 293, in mbox
  File "gui.py", line 176, in __init__
  File "lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1699, in wm_iconbitmap
TclError: bitmap "logo.ico" not defined
2017-12-14 11:46:35,273 - document_opener.gui - DEBUG - cook is expired True
2017-12-14 11:46:35,315 - document_opener.gui - ERROR - Create mbox ended with error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 293, in mbox
  File "gui.py", line 176, in __init__
  File "lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1699, in wm_iconbitmap
TclError: bitmap "logo.ico" not defined
2017-12-14 11:46:35,319 - document_opener.gui - INFO - Searching for cookies listed in cookienames parameter
2017-12-14 11:46:35,322 - document_opener.gui - ERROR - Error with mismatch parameter:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1013, in main
MismatchParameterError: Authentication cookie 'JSESSIONID, BAYEUX_BROWSER' was not found in CHROME.
To execute this command you must log-in with "Keep me logged-in" option checked.

To avoid this message and redirect the user directly to the loging page specify "LoginUrl" parameter.
```

PS: on another browsers I have the same error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one or both cookies did not have an expiration date or had expired date.  The WebDAV Ajax Library v4 and earlier required permanent cookie(s) (with expiration date).

Note that the WebDAV Ajax Library v5 was totally redesigned and use a different mechanism to pass cookies. Including it can detect session cookies (without expiration date).

Also make sure that you have the latest WebDAV Ajax Library version. Web browsers are updated rapidly and some functionality may not work with newer web browsers. Download the latest IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library build [here](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/download/).